# Find the equation of a circle that intersect two points

Tags: geometry, circles

[image]

Hello,
I tried to solve this problem. I started by putting the two equations equal to each other to find the intersect point. I got an equation which is 7y - 3x = 8. I stuck here. Can someone help me with this problem?
thanks

Comment: Solve $7y - 3x = 8$ for $x$ (or $y$) and plug it into $x^2 + y^2 = 16$.  This will give you a quadratic equation in one variable for you to solve.

Comment: User amd raised good points (comment now deleted) about searchability and such. That is why we recommend using MathJax for typesetting formulas. It is easy to learn and helps you in the future (because LaTeX is used widely). [A link to our quick MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619).

Comment: Thank you very muck for the tutorial link. I will type in the question next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the two equations equal to find the intersection points:

$x^{2}+y^{2}=2x^{2}+2y^{2}+6x-14y$

$y^{2}+x^{2}+6x-14y=0$

We have a circle equation in this step which includes the origin in itself, so the circle exists.

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you’ve pasted into your question doesn’t ask you to find the equation of a circle, but only to determine if a circle with the given properties exists. Three noncolinear points determine a circle, so the answer is “yes” unless the two given circles’ intersections are colinear with the origin (and even in that case, the line might be considered a degenerate circle with infinite radius). You’ve found the line that passes through those intersection points. Does the origin lie on this line?

Comment: No, the origin would not lie on the line equation.

Comment: @NarimanZendehrooh Well, there you go: done.